# iAd on iPad, is it working?

Tags: iphone, ipad, iad

How to integrate iAd into my iPad App? Is there a way or is it working only on iPhone with iOS4?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears its not working on the iPad yet
http://www.appleinsider.com/articles/10/06/28/iad_report_apples_ios_4_will_reach_ipad_in_november.html

Answer (score 3):

As iAd is a feature of iOS 4, and the iPad currently only runs iOS 3.2, you cannot yet use iAd on the iPad. You'll have to wait till Apple releases iOS 4(.1) for iPad, presumably in November, as @programatique mentioned.

Comment: Is the issue solved now? My app gets crashed when running on iPad 3.2 simulator